# Using a regexp for counting matches

Tags: regular-expressions

I have the following function that uses a regexp for counting matches, but I have difficulty coming up with regexp expressions to test it.

```lisp
    (defun rk-regex-count (regex rgn-beg rgn-end)
      "Count brace marks within a region with `completing-read'.
    REGEX     Regular expression.
    RGN-BEG   Marker defining start of region.
    RGN-END   Marker defining end of region."
      (interactive
       (list (read-regexp "Regex: ")
         (region-beginning)
         (region-end)))
      (save-excursion
        (let (($sum  0))
          (goto-char rgn-beg)
          (while (and (< (point) rgn-end)
                      (re-search-forward regex rgn-end t))
            (+ $sum 1))
          (message "Marks: %s Count: %d" regex $sum)
          (goto-char rgn-beg))))
```

For instance, suppose I have the following piece of code and want to count the number of opening parentheses.  What should my regex be?  Other examples or using this function would be very illuminating.

```lisp
    (interactive
       (list (read-regexp "Regex: ")
         (region-beginning)
         (region-end)))
```

Comment: For any regular expression, the value of $sum is 0. The code (+ $sum 1) never changes the value of $sum. Why don't you use the `count-matches` function?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have an error in your code. Presumably you meant this:
   `(setq $sum  (+ $sum 1))` and not this: `(+ $sum 1)`.
2. For regexps to try, it depends on what you're wanting to match, of course. Try a regexp such as this (after the fix of #1:), for instance: `([^)]*)`.

Comment: Your regexp matches "any number of any char but )".  It gives me a count of 3, but I am getting quite confused about the result.

Comment: The regexp matches `(` followed by zero or more chars other than `)`, followed by `)`. It's just an example - nothing special. Dunno what you really might want to match, and that's anyway left up to the user of your command.

Comment: You are correct.  I am simply trying to test the function a little bit.

Comment: I am getting `Invalid regexp: "Unmatched [ or [^"`

Comment: Perhaps you didn't type the whole regexp, and do so correctly. Or perhaps you didn't apply the code correction (#1) properly.

Comment: Would I just input `([^)]*)` in the minbuffer prompt?

Comment: Yes, for that example. It prompts for a regexp; you type the regexp and hit `RET`. That regexp matches what I said: `(` followed by zero or more non-`(` chars, followed by `)`. The first and third parens are literal chars to match. The second paren is part of the char-class spec `[^)]`, which specifies a char other than `)`.

Comment: On closer inspection I realised that I forgot the `)` after `^`.

Comment: The match only occurs when `()` occur on single line.  Is this how `re-search-forward` functions?

Comment: Have used `\t` as the regex to count the number of tabs if any are present.  And getting value of 3, even when there are two tabs.

Comment: *Post separate questions for separate questions.* Comments are not for Q&A. The regexp I gave as an example is just an  example of a regexp. (But it does match across any number of lines.) `[^)]` Matches any char except `)`, including newline chars.

Comment: I understand it now.  The regex matches `(interactive (list (read-regexp "Regex: ")` first, then `(region-beginning)` followed by `(region-end)`.  Rather than matching five s-exps.